# Bash: copy stdin to file

Tags: bash, stdin

I have two programs. First one is client and the second one is server. they exchange data in text format using stdin and stdout.

I would like to put proxy bash script between them and record everything coming from stdin to a file.

I tried the following code, but /tmp/f-copy.txt is empty

Proxy.sh:

```
exec 6<&0
exec 6>/tmp/f-copy.txt
server
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the `tee` command, it's what you want. From the man page:

The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

Comment: The problem is that tee waits for the end of input (as far as I know). I need something that will not block execution.

Comment: I think what he means is he doesn't want the execution to block. I'm looking for something like that too. Since `command | tee elsewhere &` terminates immediately for whatever reason, there appears to be no way to run this in the background.